# Understanding the difference between two Haskell signatures, one using forall

Tags: haskell

In this [paper](https://github.com/kosmikus/SSGEP/blob/master/LectureNotes.pdf) there is a function with the following signature:

```
vreplicate :: forall a n . SNatI n => a -> Vec a n
```

What is the difference between this signature and the one that doesn't have `forall`:

```
vreplicate :: SNatI n => a -> Vec a n
```

? I was under the impression that with no `forall`, it implicitly means the same as having `forall` in front that names all the type variables.

Comment: I'm under the same impression as you. If the paper is math heavy, they might be just using explicit notation for the sake of being explicit.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Actually, no, there is a difference if you try to compile. With `ScopedTypeVariables`, it works with `forall` and errors without. Code in case you're interested: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b288970d38595be68229

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two important cases where including a `forall` makes a difference. The first is that the location of a `forall` can change the meaning of a type -- if it comes to the left of an arrow, that means an argument to the function is "more polymorphic" than otherwise. This difference is a fundamental one; however, it does not seem to apply here.

The second difference is a syntactic (rather than fundamental) one, namely: in the presence of `ScopedTypeVariables`, variables bound by a `forall` open a typing scope, whereas variables implicitly bound without a `forall` do not. Thus, in the body of `vreplicate`, one can use the type variables `a` and `n` and be certain that they refer to the same types as mentioned in the signature of `vreplicate`. Without the `forall` (or without `ScopedTypeVariables`), uses of `a` and `n` in the body of `vreplicate` would introduce *fresh* universally quantified variables, and it would be the programmer's responsibility to ensure they were unified with the types in the signature of `vreplicate` if that were a desired. Further details are available in [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables).

Without reading the paper carefully I can't be sure, but I would strongly bet the latter is happening here.

Comment: The second paragraph is it. Thanks very much for the explanation.